# C# Foreach loop doesn't work as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor, foreach

I have a list of posts, and I have a list of opinions, 4 opinions users can vote for each post.

It's like:

```
POST1
Vote (opinion A | 10 votes), vote (opinion B | 2 votes), vote (opinion C | 1 votes), vote (opinion D | 0 votes)

POST2
Vote (opinion A | 3 votes), vote (opinion B | 4 votes), vote (opinion C | 5 votes), vote (opinion D | 7 votes)
```

For each post any user posts in his or her Diary, other users can vote 1 opinion.

In my controller I have this line to get the Diary Posts:

```
var diaryPosts = (from d in db.DiaryPosts
                  join e in db.EstadosDeAlma
                  on d.EstadosDeAlmaID equals e.ID
                  join u in db.User
                  on d.UserID equals u.ID
                  orderby d.ID descending
                  select new DiaryPostsSet
                  {
                      PostID = d.ID,
                      EstadoDeAlmaID = e.ID,
                      EstadoDeAlma = e.Title, 
                      Author = u.Nickname,
                      Thumbnail = u.Thumbnail,
                      AuthorComment = d.Content, 
                      Time = d.UpdateTime }).Take(6).ToList();
```

And I try to take for each DiaryPost, its opinions votes, and here is my problem. I have it like this:

```
List<ImpressionsSet> impressions = new List<ImpressionsSet>();

foreach (var item in diaryPosts)
{
    impressions = (from i in db.Impressions
                   select new ImpressionsSet
                   {
                       ImpressionID = i.ID,
                       ImpressionTitle = i.Impression,
                       UrlSlug = i.UrlSlug,
                       DiaryPostID = item.PostID,
                       ImpressionNum = i.DiaryImpressions.Count(d => d.DiaryPostsID == item.PostID)
                   }).ToList();
}
```

But 'impressions' var gets only the last loop. I don't know how to solve that, cuz I had only a few experience with arrays and lists in C#4.0. I don't know if I could use that like impressions[n], I tried and it doesn't work.

I also need a sample code on how I would control the results of this loop in my Razor View.
I have this now:

```
@foreach (var imp in ViewBag.ImpressionsList)
{
    if (item.PostID == imp.DiaryPostID)
    {
    <td>
        @{ string cbName = imp.UrlSlug;  }
        @{ string impression = imp.ImpressionTitle; }
        @{ string value = imp.DiaryPostID + "|" + imp.ImpressionID + "|" + Session["id"].ToString(); }
        <a class="voto" href="javascript:;" onclick="PostImpressions('@value')">@impression</a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a class="num" href="javascript:;" onclick="PostImpressions('@value')">@imp.ImpressionNum</a>
    </td>
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure if it would really work, cuz I dont have the results for the 2 posts in my impressions var, it just get the last result.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of:

```
impressions = ...
```

Do

```
impressions.AddRange( (from i in db.Impressions
               select new ImpressionsSet
               {
                   ImpressionID = i.ID,
                   ImpressionTitle = i.Impression,
                   UrlSlug = i.UrlSlug,
                   DiaryPostID = item.PostID,
                   ImpressionNum = i.DiaryImpressions.Count(d => d.DiaryPostsID == item.PostID)
               }).ToList() );
```